# Accessing data from Stackoverflow using Stack API with fromdate parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, stackexchange-api

I am trying to **scrape** questions related to Python from Stackoverflow using STACKEXCHANGE API between two given dates. I was accessing the data without key. Then I faced throttling issue and was banned for 20 hours. I read the documentation of Stack API and came to know about the API_Key. Now I am using API_Key, the problem I am facing is when I run the fetch command using following code:

```
questions = SITE.fetch('questions',tagged='python',fromdate=from_date, todate=today,filter='withbody')
```

I am getting

> error 400, 'bad_parameter'

on fromdate. However, when I remove the API_Key and run the above command, it works fine. Could anyone guide me where am I making mistake step?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Without `Key`, you can enter the values of `fromdate` and `todate` in standard date formats (i.e. yyyy-mm-dd or dd-mm-yyyy). However, when we use `Key` parameter then values of `fromdate` and `todate` should be in `Unix epoch time` format which is integer value of time.